# ruby разбить файл на массив хэшей

Tags: ruby

Есть `txt` файл со списком (строки через `\n`, поля через "\")
Требуется разбить файл на массив хэшей, то есть :

```
Иванов\Иван\Иванович\1973
Петров\Петр\Петрович\1963
Васин\Василий\Васильевич\1955
```

результат

```
arr[{fam='Иванов' name=>'Иван' otch=>'Иванович' year=>'1973'}, {},{}]
```

Comment: Зачем принимать единственный ответ как лучший, если вопросу всего час?

Comment: @Nakilon Думаете, из-за пары строк кода стоило тендер устроить? :)

Comment: @EugZol, стоило дать совет на будущее )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.read("file.txt").split("\n").map do |line|
  Hash[ %i{ fam name otch year }.zip line.split ?\\ ]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Прочитать файл, разбить на строки, отрезать у каждой строки `\n` методом `chomp`, разбить каждую строку на массив слов с помощью `split("\\")` (`\` — спецсимвол, поэтому его нужно заэкранировать). Составить из полученного массива строк ассоциативный массив (хэш) и добавить результат в конечный массив методом `push`.

```
res = []

File.open('file.txt') do |f|
  f.readlines.each do |line|
    data = line.chomp.split("\\")
    res.push({fam: data[0], name: data[1], otch: data[2], year: data[3]})
  end
end

puts res
```

Comment: Более элегантный способ
[:fam, :name, :otch, :year].each_with_index { |key, index| res[key] = data[index] }

Comment: Мысль вашу понял, но если использовать тот `res`, который у меня, то выйдет не то, что нужно. Лучше напишите ваше решение целиком в другом ответе.